# Add Empty/Null Option As First Option of HTML/Select

Tags: php, select

Using php how can I add a Empty option, and set the field to required?  This is the current code

```
<div class="qu-field">
    <?php
        $label = new HTML\Label(__('Are you shipping FedEx Or UPS?', 'query-mailer'), [
            'for' => 'carroer',
        ]);
        $label->render();

        $input = new HTML\Select([
            'id' => 'carrier',
            'name' => 'carrier',
        ], [
            new HTML\Option([
                'value' => 'FedEx',
                'selected' => false,
            ], ['FedEx']),
            new HTML\Option([
                'value' => 'UPS',
                'selected' => false,
            ], ['UPS'])
        ]);
        $input->render();
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not pure PHP, you are using a framework, but which one?

Comment: @MarkusZeller - how would I find that out?